# Resizehandle MVC5 EditorFor in IE not working (working in FF and Chrome)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using MVC5, and the latest boostrap release. I have a really easy view with an EditorFor that gets a MultiLine string:

Code:

```
[Required, DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Body { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Body, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @rows = 5 } })
```

When I open the view in Chrome or in Firefox I get resize handles, and the possibility to resize the generated textbox. However, in InternetExplorer there is no resize handle (or possibility to resize) at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Textareas have a resizehandle by default in Webkit* and Firefox desktop browsers. IE and Edge don't.

You can enable resizing in IE and Edge with [jQuery UI resizable](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/):

```
<textarea id="someId"></textarea>

<!-- TODO: insert script references to jQuery and jQueryUI here... -->
<script>
    $("#someId").resizable();
</script>
```

You can disable the resizing from Webkit and Firefox browsers with just css:

```
<textarea style="resize: none"></textarea>
```